# Creating YouTube embed code in UIWebView based on URL

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have HTML content that I'm setting on my UIWebView like this:

```
myWebView.loadHTMLString(myHTML, baseURL: nil)
```

myHTML can contain some YouTube links within its content like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJJXNJo-c3Q

How can I modify the myHTML string in order to replace each YouTube link with the YouTube embed code for that link so that it shows up in the UIWebView as an embedded video? I'm thinking regex could help but I'm not good with that.

Any help  is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a very simple function which looks for the url of given type and replaces the url with given host with a new string.

```
    func replaceUrlMatchesInText(text: NSString, forHost hostString: NSString,  replaceBlock:  (NSString) -> NSString) -> NSString {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var newText = text
    let dataDetector = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue,
        error: &error)
    if let matches = dataDetector?.matchesInString(text,
        options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportCompletion,
        range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length)) as? [NSTextCheckingResult] {
            for match in matches {
                let range = match.rangeAtIndex(0)
                let matchedString = text.substringWithRange(range)
                if matchedString.hasPrefix(hostString) {
                    let iFrameFormat = replaceBlock(matchedString)
                    let newRange = newText.rangeOfString(matchedString)
                    newText = newText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(newRange, withString: iFrameFormat)
                }
            }
    }
    return newText
}

var htmlString =  "<html><body style='background-color: transparent; color: white; font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light; padding: 20px;'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p> <p></p> <p>youtube.com/watch?v=OJJXNJo-c3Q</p>; </body></html> "

let youtubeEmbeddedVideoHtmlString = replaceUrlMatchesInText(htmlString, forHost: "youtube.com") {
    (match: NSString) in
    return "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"//\(match)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
}

println(youtubeEmbeddedVideoHtmlString)
```

This function will not only be able to extract links with "www.youtube.com", it can extract any url and you can replace it with any string you want. In this example, I simply embed it in the youtube format of the embed url.

Comment: Thank you. Using your test string worked, but it didn't work on my HTML. My HTML looks similar to this: <html><body style='background-color: transparent; color: white; font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light; padding: 20px;'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p></p>
<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJJXNJo-c3Q</p>
</body></html>

Comment: Could it be because of the new lines?

Comment: The <p> tags caused your code not to work. I added these lines and then it worked: htmlString = htmlString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<p>", withString: "<p>\n", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        htmlString = htmlString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</p>", withString: "\n</p>", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

Comment: Any suggestions for also removing <p> tags around these youtube links?

Comment: Well the problem is not with your p tag, it seems like the link you have does not have www. form and the code above compares the same.

Comment: You can replace the host check with some simple check like hasPrefix, se my edits.